# Mac OS Catalina gfortran - "ld: library not found for -lgcrt1.o"

Tags: macos, fortran, gfortran

I'm compiling a fortran program on Mac (10.15.2) with cmake and gfortran, but I'm getting the following error:

> ld: library not found for -lgcrt1.o

I found the file grcrt1.o in the folder

> /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/lib/gcrt1.o

But even if I add that to my PATH it still doesn't work.

The version of gfortran I'm using was installed with homebrew and is in

> /usr/local/bin/gfortran

gfortran is version 9.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just happened to me as well. I have Xcode 11 and 10.1 installed. For me switching back to version 10.1 helped:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode-10.1.app/
```

Comment: Three years later with OS 13 Ventura the Xcode directory no longer has a version in it.

Comment: I get the same library not found error, on 13.3, but cannot find it anywhere and the accepted answer doesn't work. Any other fixes?